# Error previewing Amazon S3 uploaded office files using office online

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, iframe, amazon-s3

We have uploaded some office files to our Amazon S3 bucket through our application. We are using office online to preview the files in the browser inside the iframe from our app. If the bucket has the office file inside the sub-directory (eg. "Test"), then the preview works properly. But when the bucket sub-directory has name ending in period (eg. "ABC Corp."), the office preview says file not found.

So far we are not sure if we need to escape the period symbol when creating the sub-directory in Amazon S3 Bucket or need to do something different when previewing in the office online.

Our javascript code snipped to preview the office files

> URL = "https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=" +
>   encodeURIComponent(PreSignedURL); var elem =
>   document.createElement("iframe"); iframe.appendChild(elem);
>   elem.src = URL ; elem.setAttribute("style", "width:100%; height:90%;
>   border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;");

Any help or feedback is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing in S3 that restricts the object key name having a dot anywhere in it.  Can you access the file via a browser with the URL?  Is this perhaps an Office limitation?

Comment: Yes, we can download the file properly via browser with the URL.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Comment: We are also facing this issue. signed s3 URLs are not working. Anyone has a solution?